# GitLab service get high CPU usage

Tags: docker, gitlab, devops, cicd, gitlab-ce

run many `kthreaddw` on gitlab 13.4.3 and have high CPU usage.

[image: GitLab CPU load is high]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/345091) the solution seems to be to stop GitLab, kill all these processes and then start GitLab :thinking_face: Though as I personally never had this I can't tell you 100% sure how to fix this.

Comment: After stop container and start again these processes killed but It starts again after several hours.